# What causes Google Cloud Run job to fail with error "Killed"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud

I'm cloning multiple repositories (using `git clone`) inside my Google Cloud Run job and one of them makes Google Cloud killing the container with exit 1. See the log:

```json
    {
      insertId: "xxx",
      labels: {
        instanceId: "xxx"
        run.googleapis.com/execution_name: "xxx",
        run.googleapis.com/task_attempt: "0",
        run.googleapis.com/task_index: "0"
      },
      logName: "xxx/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
      receiveTimestamp: "2024-03-13T09:05:28.686787232Z",
      resource: {
        labels: {
          job_name: "xxx",
          location: "xxx",
          project_id: "xxx"
        },
        type: "cloud_run_job"
      },
      textPayload: "Killed",
      timestamp: "2024-03-13T09:05:28.685133Z"
    }
```

The repository as cloned has 10.828 files and its size is 1.8 GB. The memory and CPU usage didn't exceed 50 %. It happens during `git clone git@github.com:usr/bad_repo.git`.

I assume it's related to a limit but I didn't find anything.

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Docker container with a Bash script that clones a repository like this:

```bash
git clone -q --depth 1 --no-tags --filter=blob:limit=100k git@github.com:supabase/supabase.git
```

2. Run this Docker container as [Cloud Run job](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-starting-cloudrun-jobs#0)
3. The container will exit with status code 1 triggered by Cloud Run

---

All logs:

[image]

Comment: Can you share minimal replicating steps and additional logs, if found?

Comment: @RoopaM I added steps to reproduce and all logs

Comment: I tried with this [`Dockerfile`](https://codefile.io/f/lRqbmYnJCO) and [`script.sh`](https://codefile.io/f/KJ0jYTHMzQ) following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-shell) and got same issue. After increasing memory and CPU, its working fine. I can also able to successfully run with `alphine` image with 2gb memory and 1 CPU. Can you try to increase memory and CPU? Also  share your `Dockerfile.`

Comment: Increasing the RAM helped. Makes sense now, the repository is 1.8 GB, RAM was at 2.0 GB. Likely, it didn't fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by Roopa M in the comments: Increasing the RAM helped, even though there is no spike in usage.